# How to close Internet Explorer from the Run box?

Tags: internet, internet-explorer, run-dialog

When using the Run application from Windows desktop, what command would one use to close all instances of IE?

I know you can open IE by typing "iexplore.exe" but I need a way to close IE as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What command would one use to close all instances of IE?

You can use `taskkill`

```
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe
```

---

#### Further reading

- [TASKKILL](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) - End one or more processes (by process id or image name)